# Как управлять менеджером компоновки QGridLayout?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qlayout, qgridlayout

Как управлять макетом, т.е. его размером, размером виджетов внутри макета и положением макета в окне?

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QGridLayout, QFrame


class EgoDialog(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)
    
        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.frame.setStyleSheet('background-color: red;')
        self.frame2 = QFrame()
        self.frame2.setStyleSheet('background-color: red;')
    
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.grid)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.frame)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.frame2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    win = EgoDialog()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Почитать мануал и попробовать

Comment: Дополните вопрос примером и уточните, что в нем не так и как вы хотите увидеть расположение и размеры.

Comment: Добавил макет, хотелось бы положением и размерами виджетов и самого макета управлять. Например зафиксировать все по центру с нужным размером.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс **QGridLayout** помещает элементы управления в оконную сетку.

QGridLayout принимает доступное пространство и делит его на строки и столбцы, 
а затем помещает каждый элемент управления окна в указанную ячейку.

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QGridLayout, QFrame


class EgoDialog(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)

        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.frame.setStyleSheet('background-color: red;')
        self.frame.setFixedSize(200 , 100)
        self.frame2 = QFrame()
        self.frame2.setStyleSheet('background-color: blue;')
        self.frame2.setFixedSize(200 , 100)

        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.grid.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.frame,  1, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.frame2, 2, 1)
        self.grid.setRowStretch(3, 1)

# попробуйте в работе стоки ниже, может пригодиться
#        self.grid.setSpacing(0)
#        self.grid.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.setLayout(self.grid)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    win = EgoDialog()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]